# "Zéroième": L'emploie-t-on ?

Tags: usage, adjectifs, science, académique, université

Peut-on employer l'adjectif ordinal *zéroième* ? Ex.

Le Zéroième principe de la Thermodynamique (à la Zeroth Law of Thermodynamics).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Oui, bien sûr, on peut et on doit employer **zéroième** quand le besoin s'en fait sentir.

Bien que rare, puisqu'on ordonne bien plus souvent à partir du nombre *un*, on trouve suffisamment d'occurrences de cet adjectif pour ne pas s'en priver, d'autant plus qu'il faut bien traduire *zeroth*...

> **Zéroième** principe de la thermodynamique
>
> Cette section consiste en une discussion du **zéroième** principe dela thermodynamique, qui est relié au concept de température. En cours de route nous aurons l’occasion d’introduire quelques notions de base ainsi que des concepts plus avancés qui seront discutés plus profondément plus tard dans le cours.

[Richard MacKenzie, Université de Montréal](https://studylibfr.com/doc/2946586/r%C3%A9sum%C3%A9-de-la-thermodynamique)

L'adjectif *zéroième* peut même être abordé au collège :

> **Formation des mots de la famille (dérivation, affixation, composition)**
>
> Au titre de curiosités, le professeur peut signaler quelques dérivés formés sur zéro, dont l’emploi reste rare.
>   Par exemple le verbe « zéroter » (calibrer le seuil zéro sur des appareils de mesure) et le nom correspondant « zérotage » (calibration du seuil zéro).
>
> On trouve aussi l’adjectif numéral ordinal « **zéroième** » correspondant au nombre « zéro » : « le zéroième anniversaire » (année 0).

[Ministère de l'Education nationale, Lexique et culture, Zéro](http://cache.media.education.gouv.fr/file/Lexique_et_Culture/95/7/RA18_C3_LexCulture_Zero_948957.pdf)

Comment: J'étais étonné de lire que "zérotage" était considéré comme rare, alors que c'est un mot que je lis au moins une fois par mois lorsque je reçois la douloureuse de ma carte de crédit... et je découvre alors que "zérotage" est un belgicisme dans le sens de "remboursement intégral d'une ouverture de crédit à la consommation" - peut-être parce qu'il correspond à une disposition spécifique de la législation belge sur les crédits à la consommation ? https://www.lalibre.be/economie/libre-entreprise/le-zerotage-c-est-quoi-51b8f853e4b0de6db9c977c0

Answer (score 3):

Il est attesté dans le TLFi ;

> REM. Zéroième, adj. numéral ordinal, hapax. Qui correspond au nombre zéro. La prise de la Bastille, dit l'Histoire, ce fut proprement une fête, ce fut (...) pour ainsi dire déjà le premier anniversaire de la prise de la Bastille. Ou enfin le zéroième anniversaire (PÉGUY, Clio, 1914, p. 114).

Donc, pourquoi ne pas l'utiliser ? Peut être parce qu'il n'a qu'une [occurrence](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hapax) (ou pas beaucoup plus d'une). Cela signifie qu'il n'est pas utilisé dans le langage.